# Value in C is returning null, not sure why

Tags: c

Why is the print statement is returning null?

```
#include <stdio.h>>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    char abbreviation;
    double number;
    struct Node *next;
};

void insert(char abbreviation, double number, struct Node *head) {
    struct Node *current = head;
    while(current->next != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }

    struct Node *ptr = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    ptr->abbreviation = abbreviation;
    ptr->number = number;
    current->next = ptr;

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct Node *head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    insert('n',456,head);
    printf("%s\n", head->abbreviation);
}
```

Comment: Try to use `%c` instead of `%s`

Comment: If your question is about C, please do not add the `[c++]` tag.

Comment: And since the C++ tag is gone, don't cast malloc in C.

Comment: You might want to initialize `ptr->next` in your `insert()` function as well as `head->next` before calling it ...

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a node that head->next points to, then insert the values there. You never set any values in the head node itself.

Answer (score 2):

`abbreviation` is a character, not a string.  You want `printf("%c\n", head->abbreviation);`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [UncleO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15539273/1383051), before calling `insert()` in your `main()`, set `head->abbreviation` and `head->number` to desired values and initialize `head->next` to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
    char abbreviation;
    double number;
    struct Node *next;
};
void insert(char abbreviation, double number, struct Node *head) {
struct Node *current = head;
while(current->next != NULL)
{
    current = current->next;
}

struct Node *ptr = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
ptr->abbreviation = abbreviation;
ptr->number = number;
if(head->next==NULL)
{
    head=current=ptr;
}
else
{
    current->next = ptr;
}
return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
struct Node *head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
insert('n',456,head);
printf("%s\n", head->abbreviation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the changes here :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
char abbreviation;
double number;
struct Node *next;
};

void insert(char abbreviation, double number, struct Node *head) {
struct Node *current = head;
while(current->next != NULL)
{
current = current->next;
}

struct Node *ptr = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
ptr->abbreviation = abbreviation;
ptr->number = number;
current->next = ptr;

return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
struct Node *head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
insert('n',456,head);
insert('m',453,head);
printf("%c\n", head->next->abbreviation);
printf("%c\n", head->next->next->abbreviation);
}
```